# Uploading multiple files using python object in Zapier

Tags: python, zapier

I am uploading multiple files, and I have the Python code to gather the file name and URLs and the next part is to upload the files in Dropbox.  But it seems like only the first file is being uploading.

I think I'm missing something, when Dropbox runs after this python code in zapier the expected behavior is uploading both the files?

**Python (Step 2 in Zapier):**

```py
files = [
  {'file_name': 'file_one.doc', 'file_url': 'https://www.file.com/example1'}, 
  {'file_name': 'file_two.doc', 'file_url': 'https://www.file.com/example2'}
]

return files
```

**Dropbox (Step 3 in Zapier):**
Using the file_name and file_url

Answer (score 0):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

This is a quirk of Code steps and python lists. When testing and setting up the zap, only the first array item (here, `file_one.doc`) will run. But when you turn it on, each file will be uploaded as expected.

It's an undocumented feature because the UI doesn't support it well and it's confusing (as you can tell).